# How to hide/show custom navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In my iOS application, I'm using custom `NavigationItem` (added to root view from Nib file). For default `NavigationItem` I can use

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

to hide them, but I didn't find any way to hide my custom `NavigationItem` or `removeFromSuperview`, could somebody please kindly show me some pointers?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: with `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`you hide the complete navbar and not only the navItem. As far as i understand you added the navitem as a subview. You have to keep some kind of reference to the uiview eg. with a property or a tag and then remove/hide the navItem.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, and yes I have a NavigationBar in my root view, and then my custom NavigationItem. I just tried to add a reference to the NavigationBar and send setHidden:YES to it, the NavigationBar did disappear but still taking up the vertical space. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: as the word hide suggests it just hides the navbar - > not visible but still there. i am not sure if it is possible but you can try to move the navbar with its frame property.

Comment: Oh yes, I can just move my other views up to fill the space. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` you hide the complete navbar and not only the `navItem`. As far as i understand you added the `navitem` as a subview. You have to keep some kind of reference to the `UIVview` eg. with a property or a tag and then remove/hide the `navItem`.

Since you just hide the navBar it is still there. So you can move you views with their frame property.

So I guess you it is enough to move the content views and skip the hiding / removing at all.

Answer (score 1):

you should create outlet for your navigation item and the you can animate/hide by writing code your self